# Convert PDF to PDF/A using PHP CURL

Tags: php, pdf, curl, convertapi

I'm testing the ConvertAPI PDF to PDF/A but I have some problems.
Unfortunately I cannot include the ready-made PHP client in my PHP project so I'm trying to call the API with curl from PHP.

However it always returns me http code 500

This is my code:

```
$formData = array(
'File' => '@' . trim($hdd_path . $_file_name),
'StoreFile' => true,
);

$url_conv_pdfa_convertapi_com = 'https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/pdfa?Secret=' . getConfig('external_services:convertapi_com:secret');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_conv_pdfa_convertapi_com);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $formData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 29 Jan 2024 15:04:18 GMT
server: kaulas
cara: eu-hw3-CARA-VM 1.2.1.124 cara-589585cb64-lxpkq
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 116
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
vary: Accept-Encoding
transfer-encoding: chunked

{"Code":5009,"Message":"File id is not valid."}
```

I expected file conversion to happen.

Comment: Why don't you use ConvertAPI's ready-made PHP library instead of building your own cURL requests? It's probably going to be more reliable: https://www.convertapi.com/doc/php-library. You say you "can't" do that, but give no explanation of why that is

Comment: Anyway according to https://www.convertapi.com/doc/api-endpoints#/Conversion/post_convert_pdf_to_pdfa the request needs to be multipart-form data, and actually include the file, or at least a URL from which to get the file. You're not sending anything for it to convert! If you can't / won't use the official PHP library, then look for examples of sending files using PHP/cURL with multipart/form-data - I expect you can find existing examples which will show you how the build the request structure successfully.

Comment: What do you mean by "your service"? Did you try to contact the developer support for the API you try to use? Does it work better when calling the API using Postman, such that this is **really** a PHP / cURL error?

Comment: @ADyson they are not sending just the file name, the `@` is (old) cURL syntax to make it _upload_ the file. But the documentation lists the type of the parameter as `string($binary)`, and describes it as _"File to be converted. Value can be URL or file content."_ - so I am guessing, it does not want an actual _file upload_, but simply a "normal" POST parameter named `File`, and the file content as value?

Comment: @CBroe maybe, but the doc also says that the request should be a multipart/form-data request (at least in the case where an actual file is sent, not a URL). And thanks, I didn't know about the @ syntax, I guess that predates CurlFile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip the PHP library and use your `vanilla PHP with CURL` to convert a PDF to a PDF/A using COnvertAPI, you will need to follow these steps:

`Get an API Key`: First, you need to sign up on ConvertAPI and obtain an API key.

`Install Curl for PHP`: Make sure that you have curl enabled in your PHP installation to make HTTP requests.

`Write the PHP Code`: Below is a basic example of PHP code to use ConvertAPI's PDF to PDF/A conversion service:

```
<?php

$apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY'; // Replace with your API key
$file = 'path_to_your_pdf_file.pdf'; // Replace with the path to your PDF file

$url = 'https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/pdfa?Secret=' . $apiKey;

$postData = [
    'file' => new CURLFile($file),
    'StoreFile' => true // Set to true if you want to store the file on ConvertAPI server
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($response) {
    $result = json_decode($response, true);
    if (isset($result['Files'])) {
        $downloadUrl = $result['Files'][0]['Url'];
        echo "Conversion successful. Download URL: " . $downloadUrl . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "Error in conversion: " . $response . "\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Curl error: " . curl_error($ch) . "\n";
}

?>
```

This script does the following:

- It sends a POST request to ConvertAPI's conversion endpoint with your PDF file.
- The CURLFile class is used to upload the file in a multipart/form-data request.
- It then checks the response for a file URL and prints it out.

Remember to replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual API key and 'path_to_your_pdf_file.pdf' with the path to the PDF file you want to convert.

Before running the script, ensure that your PHP setup is configured correctly with cURL and that you have the necessary permissions to access and modify the files you're working with.